# CRM 4.0 - How to add an attribute into 'To' field (email workflow)

Tags: email, workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm

I'm using Microsoft CRM 4.0 with a custom entity. I am trying to send emails dynamically to different email addresses. I have created the workflow and email template, but I can't populate the 'To' field in the email template to add one of my attributes. My attributes do not appear on the Form assistant. I have a field in my entity which is of nvarchar and format of 'email'.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot (by default) use a string attribute or a custom entity as an email target in CRM 4.0. Only certain types of built in entities can be used (normally contact, systemuser or queue).

We ended up using queues as a mechanism of storing email addresses which we did not want associated with a specific user or customer (such as shared team emails for notifications). It's a bit ugly if you also use them for anything else but works fine.